# Getting married while on H1B Visa

Tags: usa, h1-visa, marriage, india

I am on H1B visa and my Visa will expire on 09/2017 .  I am getting married soon but my fiance doesn't have passport yet.  What is the process to bring my wife ( of course after marriage :) ) to USA.

I can't find step by step process of this. Here is what I am guessing:

1. **Apply for Passport** :   Can she do this before getting married? Generally wife needs to change her last name after marriage. Will this be an issue?
2. **Apply for Visa** : Once we get the passport she will apply for H4 visa. ( H4 visa am I right here? ).  Can this process be initiated before marriage?
3. **Flight Tickets** : If all goes well and she gets the visa then get flight tickets. :)

Is this the correct process? Am I missing some step?

Comment: For the U.S., the passport/name change isn't an issue. I'll let other comment on question 2.

Comment: @ouflak the passport name change may not be an *insurmountable* issue, but the cost of waiting until after marriage (presumably delaying the entire process by a couple of weeks) may be smaller than the cost of spending the next 10 years with a passport in one's maiden name (and having to carry the marriage certificate with it or whatever).  Then again, it may not be, but the OP and his fiancée should think about it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no law restricting you to get married while on a H1b visa (As far as I know)

1. **Apply for Passport** :   Can she do this before getting married? Generally wife needs to change her last name after marriage. Will this be an issue?

   - Not sure how soon you are going to do this but I believe between getting the passport and applying for visa etc will take a while. Name change usually should not be an issue as per the [quora](https://www.quora.com/H4-Visa-Is-it-mandatory-for-my-name-to-be-included-in-my-wifes-Indian-passport-for-her-to-obtain-an-H4-as-dependent-on-me-I-have-H1B) answer here. Although read online for recent visa experiences on immihelp.com specially.
2. **Apply for Visa** : Once we get the passport she will apply for H4 visa. ( H4 visa am I right here? ).  Can this process be initiated before marriage?

H4 visa is the dependent visa - how would she be dependent on you if she is not even related to you, so I do not think so you can start the process before. I mean you can get the documentation in order. But take a look at the [checklist] and other one [here](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/h1b/h4-visa-documents.html) [3](http://www.h1bwiki.com/how-to-apply-for-h4-visa-documents-checklist/).

She would need a letter from your employer,Wedding invitation card etc. If you are going to no longer be in work status after September, unsure how her dependent visa will be approved post September?
3. **Flight Tickets** : If all goes well and she gets the visa then get flight tickets. :)

If you plan to stay in the country then may need to focus on your status first.

Disclaimer: Personal opinion based on H1b visa holder myself.